# PHPStorm plugin for Lumen just like Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, lumen

I found [this tutorial](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) to install a plugin for Laravel and have its methods completed by PHPStorm.

I does not seem to work for Lumen. Are there any solutions out there that currently support Lumen since Lumen is kind of a subset of Laravel?

Comment: I'm not into lumen, but does this helps you? It's a laravel/lumen service container binding project. https://gist.github.com/tristanpemble/51e79a6e5846d228d724 Therefore I only see a laravel plugin but your probably already have it: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7532 or this tutorial for laravel too: https://laravel-news.com/2015/01/better-laravel-integration-phpstorm/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Laravel-ide-helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) supports Lumen as of August 2015. Here's what you need to do:

Either execute the command

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper
```

or add the following to the `require` key in `composer.json`:

```
"barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "2.*"
```

Once you have installed the dependency, edit the file `bootstrap/app.php` and look for the *Register Service Providers* section and add the following line:

```
$app->register(Barryvdh\LaravelIdeHelper\IdeHelperServiceProvider::class);
```

After that, you just need to create the `_ide_helper.php` file with the following command:

```
php artisan ide-helper:generate
```

Comment: January 2018: Not working. Getting a bunch of `class not found` errors thrown with the artisan generate command.

Comment: Have you tried "composer require league/flysystem"
(https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper/issues/723) ? it worked for me